# Error in ezANOVA: One or more cells is missing data

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, anova

I have the following code:

```
positive %>% ezANOVA(dv = .(Scores), wid = .(ID), within = .(Time), between = .(Group), detailed=TRUE,type=3)
```

However, I keep getting the error:

**Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  :
One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.**

I can't see where the error is in my data!

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my data:

```
structure(list(Group = c("SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC"), Time = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
), Scores = c(18, 24, 31, 11, 14, 23, 17, 19, 10, 16, 22, 19, 
19, 23, 20, 14, 17, 29, 20, 16, 30, 26, 18, 21, 20, 19, 15, 39, 
11, 15, 28, 35, 16, 10, 15, 17, 21, 23, 12, 17, 22, 13, 17, 13, 
17, 18, 19, 17, 16, 24, 20, 22, 19, 18, 24, 13, 24, 28, 24, 26, 
13, 28, 10, 24, 32, 34, 36, 16, 25, 28, 30, 27, 24, 19, 19, 20, 
20, 10, 22, 15, 12, 20, 26, 17, 21, 24, 27, 31, 16), ID = 1:89), row.names = c(NA, 
-89L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would be so grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `ezANOVA`, but the error message suggests that some combinations of your predictor/independent variables aren't present in your data and that `ezANOVA` can't handle this sitiation.

Indeed, some combinations are missing:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Scores, Time, Group) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
  complete(Scores, Time, Group) 
# A tibble: 108 x 4
   Scores  Time Group     N
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <int>
 1     10     1 HC        1
 2     10     1 SH        1
 3     10     2 HC        1
 4     10     2 SH        1
 5     11     1 HC       NA
 6     11     1 SH        2
 7     11     2 HC       NA
 8     11     2 SH       NA
 9     12     1 HC       NA
10     12     1 SH       NA
```

On a quick skim reading of the `ez` documentation, I believe the `ezANOVA` function works only with *balanced* data.  The unequal replication in your data set means that it is not balanced.  You may need to find another approach.